# Google Analytics don't count all of edge.create events

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-analytics

I have problem with tracking Facebook like button clicks using Google Analytics.

Tracking is working fine when I'm testing it, but on production server about 80% of events are missing from statistics.

I have checked documentation about the topic:

- http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html
- http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSocial.html

I have checked tracked users browsers/OS in my statistics and distribution is same as whole site. So it's not browser/OS specific problem.

Here is my tracking code:

```
function trackEvents() {
    function getId(location) {
        // example location: http://inprl.pl/relikt/471/
        var match = location.match(/\/relikt\/(\d+)\//);
        if(match.length > 0)
            return match[1];
    }
    function trackEvent(event, categoryName, eventName, getLocation) {
        FB.Event.subscribe(event, function(response) {
            var id = getId(getLocation(response));
            if(id)
                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', categoryName, eventName, id]);
        });
    }
    trackEvent('edge.create', 'Edge', 'Create', function(request){ return request; });
    trackEvent('comment.create', 'Comment', 'Create', function(request){ return request.href; });
};
```

trackEvents is called after _gaq was created and also after Facebook was inited.

Do you have any idea why my events may vanishing?

Comment: How often does `_gaq` get pushed up to the ganalytics server?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation about "Implicit Count"? That might explain the discrepancy.